# Fazer pesquisa somente de um tipo de registro no banco de dados e mostrar no DataGrid

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

Como faz para fazer uma pesquisa no banco e mostrar no `DataGrid`, so que eu seleciono uma categoria

não estou sabendo como fazer esse tipo de busca no banco, quando eu selecionar no `ComboBox1` a palavra ativo, ele me traz somente os produtos ativos, porém eu queria fazer fazer o  meu `textBox` pesquisar somente o nome dos produtos ativos.

vamos supor que tenho dois produtos com o mesmo nome, porém um está ativo e o outro inativo, se eu selecionar ativo ele busca somente esse nome que esta ativo

código que estou utilizando(ao menos tentando fazer isso):

```
 private void txtBusca_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.Text == "Ativo")
        {
            string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE Nome LIKE (@Nome)";

            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;"))
            {
                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(strSelect, conn);
                //Passagem por parâmetros.
                da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtBusca.Text + "%");
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "Nome");
                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables["Nome"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: Mas qual é o problema ao certo? Podia detalhar mais a sua questão?

Comment: @JoãoMartins dei uma editada na pergunta, vê por favor se ficou melhor de entender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens que usar no teu query outro filtro para te trazer só os activos,
presumindo que isso já está marcado na tabela Produto.

```
string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE Nome LIKE (@Nome) AND Activos=true";
```

Comment: cara acho que é quase isso porem ainda esta dando erro, eu registro o produto como ativo (selecionando um `checkbox`) no banco tem uma coluna de `Status` onde é marcado se esta ativo ou inativo

Comment: tentei dar uma adaptada assim 
`string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE Nome AND status='Ativo' LIKE (@Nome)";`
porém não me trouxe nenhum registro

Comment: aqui pela logica que você mandou adaptei e consegui, valeu XD

`string strSelect = "SELECT * FROM Produto WHERE status='Ativo' AND nome  LIKE (@Nome)";`